# problem rendering a camera obscura

Tags: rendering, lighting

I'm trying to render a camera obscura, the light effect shows up in the viewport but doesn't render

[image]

Here is the blender file:
[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Here is the blender file[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=YkeJomNK" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/YkeJomNK/)

Answer (score 1):

You have an object called *boolean parquet* that is disabled for preview but enabled for render, disable it or it will obstruct your camera:

[image]

Comment: I was thinking one day I should make an addon to check this kind of thing, and others.

Comment: @L0Lock That would be a good idea   ;)